# Data Integrity in DB Level in front of Web Services

Tags: java, database, web-services, web-applications, architecture

Is there a possible architecture that a developer can think of when it comes to extending a web application by introducing Web Services to the existing architecture or vice-verse. The main concern in this context is the data integrity and security.

The following images will suggest two approaches that a developer can think of.

[image: Scenario One]

This architecture indicates that all the request should be handled by an individual service layer. Therefore, only the service layer can communicate with the Data Base and satisfy request for both the web application and the gate way.

[image: Scenario Two]

The second approach shows the web application is directly communicating with DB. For an example an Admin Portal. Meantime there can be an external web services also communicating with the DB. This approach may lead to Data Integrity Violating scenarios. However, introducing external web services might be easier than refactoring an existing Web Application to call a web service from developer end. Hence, can we still compromise for the long term consequences by having external web service and a separate web application instead of both the Web Application and the Gateway being catered with a single web service layer. Any reasonable comment on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could build an API that has access to everything. In other word, the web application could work trough a rest/rpc api using Ajax/WebSockets.

Since everything goes through the API, data integrity shouldn't be enforced at any time. Also, you'll get a clear separation from Client, Api and Database.

This will allow you to replace the database by anything else without breaking other parts of your system.

Comment: Thanks for the post. So would you suggest going with the first approach that means having only one service which communicates with the DB would be the better way ?

Comment: Mostly like the first but instead just expose everything as an API. There is no need to make an external API for mobile and expose something else for web apps. You'll save more time to have everything as an API. things like oauth can be use to restrict access to APIs and its standard enough that it can be easily implemented by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally advise to have at least a shared data access layer which handle data validation and persistence.

The best way would be however as defined in your first diagram with a shared service layer to factorize transaction management which should be defined at this level. You could so take advantage of custom transaction isolation and / or locking policy in order to ensure Data integrity. Public service layer methods could be in this case directly exposed as rest services and consumed by both mobile and web apps (gateway / API component is not necessary).

All of this will depend on the estimated time to refactor the legacy app architecture on a way and to duplicate data access logic (and business one ???) on the other. Of course the duplication will decrease maintainability and extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to answer this question on several projects; there's a 3rd option which you don't mention, which is my favourite.

The problem with option 1 - "web services as persistence and business logic layer" is that it introduces a lot of additional moving parts into the design. Those moving parts are expensive - you have to write, test and maintain a lot more code, and very often the services you want from your web services to run your own application are not the ones that would make sense to a 3rd party developer. 
You are also introducing a potentially significant performance and scalability risk - calling a web service which calls a database is measurably slower than just calling the database.

The second option - duplicating business logic across web app and service layer - has all the problems of duplication.

The option I prefer is to develop the business logic layer as a separate component, and have it used by both the web app and the web services; each application uses the component as a library. This means you have to have separate teams - the "library" team and the "app" teams - but you avoid duplication, and you avoid invoking a bunch of web services every time you have to render a web page.

The business logic layer is responsible for persistence - including making sure that database consistency is honoured, and managing transactions. As the business logic layer is shared between both the web app and the web services, this logic is concentrated into a single code base, and - ideally - made entirely transparent to the apps.

The web services now do far less. Their job is to handle incoming requests, translate them into method invocations on the business logic component, and returning any response data in the appropriate format (XML, JSON). They may offer "coarse grained" service requests and map them onto several more granular business logic methods. They may deal with authentication, authorization, request throttling etc. They just don't deal with the actual business logic.

Comment: +1
You still can have a shared service layer whose some public method are exposed as web-services for mobile app but called directly by the web presentation layer (if deployed on the same server) to avoid performance issue

Comment: Thanks for the post. But in your case, in the 3rd option how you maintain the integrity and transactions. Can your business logic layer address the integrity and transactions concurrently ?

Comment: The business logic layer manages persistence - including the integrity requirements and transactions.

Comment: Well if so, i don't see how it avoids you some refactoring. What does remain in the "service layer" in this case ?

Comment: I've updated the answer - the service layer manages the service, but not the business logic.